# Django forms passed instance object gets overridden in is_valid

Tags: python, django, memory, copy

I was working on a Django view that updates the a certain model object `x`. In POST method, I initiate a `ModelForm` and pass an `instance` of the model object `x`. But when I try to use `x` object inside `if form.is_valid():` block, some values in `vars(x)` go `None`. Here's the snippet to explain the scenario.

```py
class MyUpdateView(generic.View):
    form_class = MyModelForm
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        model_obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=kwargs.get("pk"))
        # Example: {"emp": 113, "project": 22, "salary": 28000}
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=model_obj)
        print(vars(model_obj)) # works fine, shows all the data

        if form.is_valid():
            print(vars(model_obj)) # few values go None, not reusable
            # Example: {"emp": None, "project": None, "salary": 28000}
```

As we can see, when the vars checked inside the `form.is_valid()`, something happens to the passed `instance` object.

What could be possibly reason behind this?

Comment: It seems unlikely this is your entire code, as you're not passing the object, you're getting the instance directly from the DB based on the pk you pass. This does not change when you call `form.is_valid()`. Good effort at getting a minimum reproducible example, but I think you've cut out the bit causing the problem :)

Comment: Wait, you know what - I'm lying to you! This was new to me actually :) https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14885 - this behaviour is as expected by the looks of it.